# Flip animation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Can anyone suggest any library/plugin in Javascript/jQuery that will help achieve the following?

http://cl.ly/2n1A2r0l1w1B

It looks like this is a well timed combination of move, scale and rotate transformations. I found this plugin: [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), but I would like to know if there's any other solution that would get me closer to the animation shown in the video.

Comment: StackOverflow is focused on code-related questions, not for finding plug-ins.

Comment: I haven't downloaded the video, but most flipping animations use a simple `3d-transform`

Comment: @Diodeus you can post code if you want to :) Seriously, SO is full of "looking for solution" questions. I don't think this is an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout if this helps:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

You can tweak it as you want and get the required effect.